# How to select position based on some quantity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table #1 - **Student**:

```
+------+-------+
|Roll  |  Name |
+------+-------+
|   1  |    A  |
|   2  |    B  |
|   3  |    C  |
+------+-------+
```

Table #2 - **Mark**:

```
+------+------+
| Roll | Mark |
+------+------+
|   1  |  85  |
|   3  |  95  |
+------+------+
```

Output needs to be:

```
+-------+------+-------+---------+
| Roll  | Name | Mark  |Position |
+-------+------+-------+---------+
|   1   |   A  |  85   |    2    |
|   2   |   B  |  0    |    3    |
|   3   |   C  |  95   |    1    |
+-------+------+-------+---------+
```

What should be the query to get the output? I think the `rank` function is to be used, but don't know to use it...

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to join two tables and then use `RANK()`.

**Query**

```
select *, Position = rank() over(
    order by t.Mark desc
)
from(
    select t1.Roll, t1.Name, coalesce(t2.Mark, 0) as Mark
    from student t1
    left join Mark t2
    on t1.Roll = t2.Roll
)t
order by t.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Join and Rank() function.

Query

```
select T1.Roll, T1.Name, isnull(T2.Mark,0) Mark, rank() over(order by mark desc) Position 
from STUDENT T1 left join MARK T2 
on T1.Roll = T2.Roll order by T1.Roll
```